# How to extract a segment of a binary file based on starting and ending hex strings

Tags: grep, sed, awk, hexdump

I have a large binary file (several hundred GBs) and I want to extract a segment from it. I know the hex strings of the beginning and ending points.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution (assuming you can make a copy of file) could use the following example

1. assume start pattern is hex 4f 0f 87 82
2. assume end pattern is hex fb 8c e2 a0
3. assume input file is called `tf` and has length 5000 bytes

then

make a copy of `tf` to a new file `blah` with start pattern changed

```
$ LC_ALL=C sed 's/'`printf "\x4f\x0f\x87\x82"`'/'`printf "AAAA"`'/'  <tf > blah
```

now find location where `tf` and `blah` differ (*note - sed writes an extra byte containing a newline at the end of the modified file, so we compare up to the length of the original file, `tf`. The generated file `blah` should be one byte longer*).

```
$ cmp -n 5000 -b tf blah
```

this will give a byte offset, bs, where files differ e.g.,

```
tf blah differ: byte 4337, line 10 is 117 O 101 A
```

now do same for ending pattern

```
 $ LC_ALL=C sed  's/'`printf "\xfb\x8c\xe2\xa0"`'/'`printf "AAAA"`'/'  < tf > blah2
 $ cmp -n 5000 -b tf blah2
 tf blah2 differ: byte 4433, line 10 is 373 ? 101 A
```

now use `dd` to extract portion of interest

```
dd if=tf skip=4336 bs=1 count=100 > fbit
```

Some extra notes:

1. some versions of sed support a `-b` option that treats the input file as binary. Other versions have a `-z` option that separates lines by NUL characters. Either way matching patterns containing a new line, or split over a new line, has not been tested.
2. the `count=100` will depend on the length of the pattern matched and whether the matched pattern is to be included in the extract (that was not clear in the question). The general formula is **count = (end offset) − (start offset) + (size of end pattern)**. The pieces for the specific example are 4433-4337+1, which give 97 bytes. That is from the start of the begin pattern up to and including the first byte of the end pattern. An extra 3 bytes are then added to give 100 in this example, because the final pattern had four bytes and the example includes the final pattern. If the final pattern was not wanted then `count=96` would be the value.
3. an approach that is more robust to new lines and using the hexdump command is possible. I have not fully tested that approach. It would essentially use hexdump with a little bit of sed, grep and tr to convert the original binary file to a hex in ascii form. Then the same process could be applied, but with more fiddly arithmetic etc.... The hexdump command needed would be

   `hexdump -v -x tf | sed s/'^[0-9]*\(.*\)/\1/' | sed s'/ *//g' | grep '[0-9]' | tr -d '\n' > tf.txt`
4. After the `hexdump` step the same process of `sed` and `cmp` could be employed. The pattern to match would have to be updated to use hexdump ascii characters not the raw hex print.
5. This approach should also handle newline characters.
6. `LC_ALL=C` seems to be needed on OSX by default. Without it the `sed` command gives an error `RE error: illegal byte sequence`. This may not be true on all platforms and/or OS distributions.

Comment: (1) How do you get `96`? (Hint: Think about it.  I believe that it's wrong.) (2) This will not work if one of the known bytes is hex `0A`.  Can you extend your answer to cover that case? (3) Is `LC_ALL=C` needed?  Can you explain why? (4) Similarly, can you explain why `-n 5000` is needed? (5) Please research “UUOC”. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: edited - thx for info.

Comment: I meant to say that I thought `98` was wrong (the `96` was a typo).  This is because your answer shows an example end pattern that is ***four*** bytes.  Otherwise, good work.

Comment: Of course, all you need to do is **size = (end offset) − (start offset) + (size of end pattern)**. Breaking the 4 down into 1+3 is just adding complication.